# Penalize error on one category svm sklearn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I've got ~100 data elements for one class, and ~6000 for another class. When I create a svm using the data, it just returns the majority category label for every new element I try to predict on. Is there a way to penalize misclassification of the minority category with the sklearn svm, so that I can actually use all my data elements and not have to sample 100 elements from the majority category to use in testing?

Comment: have you tried `sample_weight` in the [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC.fit) arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVC has the following parameter you can use

```
class_weight : {dict, 'auto'}, optional
    Set the parameter C of class i to class_weight[i]*C for
    SVC. If not given, all classes are supposed to have
    weight one. The 'auto' mode uses the values of y to
    automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to
    class frequencies.
```